# How to add() to a static class that extends arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, static

So I think I've been trying to do the impossible, and I just want to make sure I'm right about that.

The add() method for ArrayList is not static, therefore any subclass of ArrayList must be instantiated in order to have anything added to it, right?

So if I want to have a class that extends ArrayList to provide some new functions for managing a set of objects, I have to actually create an instance of the subclass?

If that is the case, is it possible to instantiate it through a static initializer like this:

```
static ArrayList<object> manager = new ArrayList<object>();
```

Even though the variable is static, would this be considered an instance that is created when the class loads? And how do I know when it gets created, so I can make sure the code that references manager is not going to have problems? I'd have to instantiate it only once at the beginning of my code, because I want to use the same ArrayList multiple times (adding, removing, etc) as time goes on.

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: Any subclass of any class must be instantiated in order to do anything. So, *Even though the variable is static, would this be considered an instance that is created when the class loads?* Yes. Yes it would.

Comment: Generally speaking - passing things around as parameters (a-la dependency injection) rather than referring to them as global variables is preferable and you should consider doing that instead. Mutable global state is really hard to debug and reason about.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to programming, and your comment kinda went over my head. What is dependency injection? And how would I go about using that instead of what I'm doing now?

Comment: @zephos2014 basically - it means that you pass things around via function parameters as arguments instead of having a global reference to them. You pass your array list everywhere it needs to be used.

Comment: Static instance variables and `static {}` blocks are run somewhere after the class definition has been loaded and before any other of its methods (constructors included) is run. You don't need to instantiate your subclass if your methods are *static*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure it is not null, you can do this:

```
private static final ArrayList<Object> manager;
static {
    //Static blocks are automatically called
    manager = new ArrayList<Object>();
    //You can use any of the needed methods here as well, or even add things to manager.
    //Note that this is basically the same as assigning it beforehand, and certainly not required.
    //But it does allow, say, loading it from a file or however you need it.
}
```

You could **alternatively** create a method that checks if the instance is `null`, and if it is, create an instance:

```
private static void instIfNull() {
    if (manager == null) {
        manager = new ArrayList<object>();
    }
}
```

Then you would call that in all of the local functions.

Comment: Your static initializing block is equivalent to the OP static declaration code, AFAIK (since inside your `static {}` there's nothing else).

Comment: Yes, it is roughly identical.  The only reason why I put it there is that it allows using `manager.put` and similar.  I'm going to edit my awnswer to make that clearer.

Answer (score 1):

print the refernce variable's position in memory this will tell you the JVM has created it.

Do this:

```
system.out.println(manager);
```

This will print the objects position in memory and this will tell you it is created.
Hope this helps.
P.S the display of the objects position in memory might look like a whole lot of junk at first glance but it does have meaning.

Comment: That's a cool idea. I will remember that for when I have doubts.

Comment: Yes, I just figured out how to do that. New to SO.

Comment: There is transparent tick under my answer vote. I think if you click that it means you accepted my answer. That's what I saw on other answeres for questions. I'm also knew so that's what I think.

Comment: Oh I guess only one answer can be checked at a time. Sorry man. I think the answer below yours was a little more helpful, but thanks all the same.